# Prove that $\dim E=\dim F=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

$E$ and $F$ are two subspaces of the inner product space $H$. $E,F\neq\{0\}$. If there exists a constant $\alpha>0$ such that $$|\langle x,y\rangle|=\alpha\|x\|\|y\|$$
for all $x\in E$ and $y\in F$, how to prove that $\dim E=\dim F=1$?

Comment: Try Cauchy Schwarz

Comment: This is not true, one can have $E$ or $F=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Answer (score 2):

*I suppose that the base field is $\mathbb R$.*

Take $e \in E$ and $f_1,f_2 \in F$ all having norm equal to one. Even if it means switching $f_i$ to $-f_i$, we can suppose that $\langle e,f_i\rangle \gt 0$.

We have

$$\langle e, f_1\rangle=\langle e, f_2\rangle=\alpha$$ and
$$4 \alpha^2= \langle e, f_1+f_2\rangle^2 = \alpha^2 \Vert f_1 + f_2 \Vert^2 = 2 \alpha^2+2\alpha^2 \langle f_1, f_2\rangle^2.$$

Therefore $\vert \langle f_1, f_2\rangle \vert = 1$. Which means that whatever $f_1,f_2$ are and according to Cauchy-Schwarz equality case $f_1,f_2$ are colinear. We can conclude that $\dim F =1$ and also to $\dim E=1$ by symmetry as desired.

Comment: How to consider the case when the base field is $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Almost the same. Just use $\Vert f_1+f_2\Vert^2 = 2 +2 \Re \langle f_1,f_2\rangle$ in the case of a complex base field.

Comment: I have tried but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Can you write down what you tried by updating your question?